# Run counter timer for total time currently spending since previous time

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to run timer for office time checkIn and checked out. I have a checked In time e.g 09:27:00 (in 24hr format) and i thought to   run timer (current time+ checked In time) + timer running , so i can understand how much time spending since last checked In.(might be there could be some better idea to achieve this)

What i thought, i have to add current time  with 09:27:00(checked In time) and run timer by adding +1/seconds and show timer!

But i do not know how to do in typescript!

Expected output: e.g You are currently spending 04:10:56 (this will be +1 sec increment) time since checked In.
[image]

```
 convertFrom24To12Format = (time24: any) => {
    const [sHours, minutes] = time24.match(/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})/).slice(1);
    const period = +sHours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
    const hours = +sHours % 12 || 12;

    return `${hours}:${minutes} ${period}`;
  };
   

  convertFrom12To24Format = (time12: any) => {
    console.log('value::::', time12);
    const [sHours, minutes, period] = time12
      .match(/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2}) (AM|PM)/)
      .slice(1);
    const PM = period === 'PM';
    const hours = (+sHours % 12) + (PM ? 12 : 0);

    return `${('0' + hours).slice(-2)}:${minutes}`;
  };
```

Comment: Not sure, why no one has answered this question. But now i have solved by taking help from https://chat.openai.com/